# Is it possible to define an element group which contains attribute groups?

Tags: xsd

I am defining an xsd containing multiple complex elements which repeat a similar structure under different elements.
Sample:

```
<keys>
  <add-key>
    <add key="new key" value="v1">
  </add-key>
  <del-key>
    <add key="bad key" value="v2">
  </del-key>
</keys>
```

What is the correct way to define the following? I'm getting schema cannot be parsed when using this segment of code.

```
<xs:complexType name="keyType">
  <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="add">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="keyAttributeGroup"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 

<xs:attributeGroup name="keyAttributeGroup">
  <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance all the names a *element* of *type keyType* could have (`add-key, del-key`), then **a possible solution is to use an unnamed choice**:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="keys">
        <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="add-key" type="keyType" />
                    <xs:element name="del-key" type="keyType" />
                </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="keyType">
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="add">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="keyAttributeGroup" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:attributeGroup name="keyAttributeGroup">
        <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

If the element can have any random name (`add-key, del-key, whatever`) the closest solution I know it's to use `xs:any`.

Comment: That is definitely an interesting way to look at it! Although, I am looking for a way to define an element group under which each element there will be an attribute group. The example I provided was a unique case of the general problem I'm facing. But, I must say again your answer is great!